# How to use react-pdf library with Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-pdf

I'm trying to use a npm library that help me to render a pdf document. I found react-pdf but it doesn't have the types for TypeScript yet, so I'm using it as I show below:

```
let Document = require('react-pdf');
let Page = require('react-pdf');

class PdfViewer extends React.Component<PdfViewer.Props, PdfViewer.State> {

  constructor(props: PdfViewer.Props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      numPages: null,
      pageNumber: 1,
    };

  }
  onDocumentLoadSuccess = ( numPages: number ) => {
    this.setState({ numPages });

  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps: PdfViewer.Props) {
    // this.setState(CsvViewer.parse(nextProps.data));
  }

  render() {
      const {url} = this.props;
      const { pageNumber, numPages } = this.state;

      const buffer = data as ArrayBuffer;

      return ( 
      <div>
        <Document
          file={url}
          onLoadSuccess={this.onDocumentLoadSuccess}
        >
          <Page pageNumber={pageNumber} />
        </Document>
        <p>Page {pageNumber} of {numPages}</p>
      </div>
      );

  }
}
```

But it's throwing this error:

> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components)
>   or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.

I found [this](https://github.com/wojtekmaj/react-pdf/issues/34) in GitHub but it didn't help me to much.
I went to the [documentation](https://github.com/wojtekmaj/react-pdf) of the library, and I passed an object in the file parameter as they show to do but the same error. I think is something else. 
I went to the source code of the `react-pdf` library and I think this is the function they use to get the file from the parameter:

```
findDocumentSource = async () => {
    const { file } = this.props;

    if (!file) {
      return null;
    }

    // File is a string
    if (typeof file === 'string') {
      if (isDataURI(file)) {
        const fileUint8Array = dataURItoUint8Array(file);
        return { data: fileUint8Array };
      }

      displayCORSWarning();
      return { url: file };
    }

    // File is PDFDataRangeTransport
    if (file instanceof PDFDataRangeTransport) {
      return { range: file };
    }

    // File is an ArrayBuffer
    if (isArrayBuffer(file)) {
      return { data: file };
    }

    /**
     * The cases below are browser-only.
     * If you're running on a non-browser environment, these cases will be of no use.
     */
    if (isBrowser) {
      // File is a Blob
      if (isBlob(file) || isFile(file)) {
        return { data: await loadFromFile(file) };
      }
    }

    // At this point, file must be an object
    if (typeof file !== 'object') {
      throw new Error('Invalid parameter in file, need either Uint8Array, string or a parameter object');
    }

    if (!file.url && !file.data && !file.range) {
      throw new Error('Invalid parameter object: need either .data, .range or .url');
    }

    // File .url is a string
    if (typeof file.url === 'string') {
      if (isDataURI(file.url)) {
        const { url, ...otherParams } = file;
        const fileUint8Array = dataURItoUint8Array(url);
        return { data: fileUint8Array, ...otherParams };
      }

      displayCORSWarning();
    }

    return file;
  };
```

But I doubt the error is here but I can't figure out what could be. The version of `react` I'm using is 16.8.2  and 4.0.2 for `react-pdf`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is incorrect:

```
let Document = require('react-pdf');
let Page = require('react-pdf');
```

You are importing the *entire* module when you do this. That means that `Document` and `Page` both contain all the modules of `react-pdf`. Instead what you want to do is either import ReactPDF and reference those modules:

```
const ReactPDF = require('react-pdf');

<ReactPDF.Document />
<ReactPDF.Page />
```

*or* you could use destructuring:

```
import { Document, Page } from 'react-pdf';

//or

const { Document, Page } = require('react-pdf');
```

If TypeScript complains about missing declarations, just add a `@types` folder to your project, create a subfolder inside of it called `react-pdf` and file inside that folder called `index.d.ts` with one line:

```
declare module "react-pdf"
```

Comment: let me try that

Comment: I tried now your second suggestion but I got this:` Try `npm install @types/react-pdf` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'react-pdf' `. I created the @types folder in the src folder, should I put it outside at the same level of `node_modules`?

Comment: I always put mine in src so the full path would be `./src/@types/react-pdf/index.d.ts` but I'm not sure if it actually matters where it is at all

Comment: My bad, I stopped and started again the project and it worked, thanks again

Answer (score 3):

- first add types
- if you are using create react app you should add:

```
import { Document, Page, pdfjs } from "react-pdf/dist/esm/entry.webpack";
pdfjs.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc =`//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/${pdfjs.version}/pdf.worker.js`;
```

Comment: Where does this solution come from (the `react-pdf` docs?), and why does it work?